# Trying to instantiate an Object in @Before

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to test HerePoiSearchTransformers.class but I get the following error: **java.lang.NullPointerException**

I have the following unit test **testTransformProviderResponse**:

```
public class HerePoiSearchTransformerTest {
    private static final String ADDRESS_CATEGORIES = "city-town";

    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    private final HerePoiSearchTransformer transformer = new HerePoiSearchTransformer();

    // private final AddressDistrictCity addressDistrictCity = new AddressDistrictCity();
    private AddressDistrictCity addressDistrictCity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Whitebox.setInternalState(transformer, "hereAddressCategories", ADDRESS_CATEGORIES);
        transformer.initHereCategoryClassification();

        addressDistrictCity = new AddressDistrictCity();
    }
    
      @Test
    public void testTransformProviderResponse() throws IOException, OnlinePOIsearchException {
        final ProviderResponse hereResponse = new ProviderResponse();
        hereResponse.setContent(content);

        final List<PoiBE> pois = transformer.transformToPoiBEs(hereResponse);
        final PoiBE poi = pois.get(0);
        assertThat(poi.getDetails()).isNotNull();
    }
 }
```

!! **The problem is that AddressDistrictCity  from AbstractHereTransformers is null** !!

I have the following structure:

```
 class HerePoiSearchTransformers extends AbstractHereTransformer 
   Methods: 
        transformToPoiBEs(...) {
            transformItems(...);
         }
        transformItems(...) {
              addAddress(final AddressDO resultAddress, final PoiBE poi)
        }
   
   class AbstractHereTransformers {
       @Inject
       private AddressDistrictCity addressDistrictCity;

       protected void addAddress(final AddressDO resultAddress, final PoiBE poi) {
            addressDistrictCity.setDistrictAndCity(address, resultAddress.getDistrict(), resultAddress.getCity());
    }
  }
```

I though that `private final AddressDistrictCity addressDistrictCity = new AddressDistrictCity();` will fix the problem.

Comment: I updated the post, from transformToPoisBEs(..) is called transformItems(..)

Comment: You have created an AddressCity, but it has not been used anywhere. The addresscity inside the transformer is a different one and since it is initialized while creating a transformer object, its value is null.

Comment: You're not using Mockito anywhere in this post.

Comment: @George I updated my post

Comment: @DeepakPatankar I understood, but how can I create then an instance of addresscity in AbstractHereTransformers ?

Comment: @ela_ela I added an answer which can help. Can you please check if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AddressDistrictCity` inside `HerePoiSearchTransformer` is not initialized.

You created a variable `addressDistrictCity = new AddressDistrictCity();` but this is not the object which is present inside `transformer`.

You can use `@InjectMocks` on `HerePoiSearchTransformer` and `@Mock` on `AddressDistrictCity`

```
@InjectMocks private HerePoiSearchTransformer transformer;
@Mock private AddressDistrictCity addressDistrictCity;
```

The JUnit framework will take care of replacing the addressDistrictCity with the required mock object in the `AbstractHereTransformers` class.

Comment: @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

Comment: @InjectMocks
    private HerePoiSearchTransformer transformer;

Comment: @Mock
    private AddressDistrictCity addressDistrictCity;

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you :)